# React calendar color an array of dates in production with css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, react-calendar

I am using react calendar. I have an assay of dates ['dd-mm-yyyy', 'dd-mm-yyyy'...etc].
I am using react  and css modules. In development mode I just imported the css modules and returned the styles.highlight class and the specific dates are working. But in production, nothing works. Anyone have this problem? Or any work around? I tried to return also a css object (css in JS ) but with the same result...

```
 <Calendar
                value={date} 
                onChange={handleOnchangeDate} 
                onClickDay={value => handleSelectDay(value)}
                tileClassName={({ date, view }) => {
                  if(props.workoutDays.find(x => x === date.toLocaleDateString())){
                   return  styles.highlight 
                  }
                }} />
```